# SQLiteException: table already exists

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I added to my DB the table called "MEDIA_TABLE" and i got the following error code:

```
05-15 20:56:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5968): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table personal_stats already exists (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE personal_stats (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, pictures TEXT, videos TEXT);
```

My second table works fine.

i tried to uninstall my app and install it and it wont work, maybe there is a limit of tables in DB?

Here is my onCreate code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_EXERCISE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_WEIGHT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_REPS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_SET_TIME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_WORKOUT_TIME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_DISTANCE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_SPEED + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_REST_TIME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_NUMBER_OF_SETS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_NOT_ON_LIST_EXERCISE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_HERAT_BEAT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_CALORIES + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_COMMENT + " TEXT);");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SECOND_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_AGE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_AGE_PW + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_GENDER + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_HEIGHT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_HEIGHT_PW + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_BODY_WEIGHT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_BODY_WEIGHT_PW + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_PROFILE_PIC + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_FAT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_FAT_PW + " TEXT);");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " +  MEDIA_TABLE + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PICS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_VIDEO + " TEXT);");

}       

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SECOND_TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MEDIA_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);   
}

EDIT :
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + SECOND_TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + MEDIA_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);   
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` instead of `CREATE TABLE`. Your code would then look like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_EXERCISE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_WEIGHT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_REPS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_SET_TIME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_WORKOUT_TIME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_DISTANCE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_SPEED + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_REST_TIME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_NUMBER_OF_SETS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_NOT_ON_LIST_EXERCISE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_HERAT_BEAT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_CALORIES + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_COMMENT + " TEXT);");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + SECOND_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_AGE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_AGE_PW + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_GENDER + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_HEIGHT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_HEIGHT_PW + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_BODY_WEIGHT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_BODY_WEIGHT_PW + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_PROFILE_PIC + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_FAT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_FAT_PW + " TEXT);");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" +  MEDIA_TABLE + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PICS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_VIDEO + " TEXT);");

}       

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SECOND_TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MEDIA_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);   
}
```

Comment: you should change all the create statements like this.

Comment: I found my mistake, your code is good thanks :)
I did the same name for 2 tables.

Comment: can I upgrade without deleting old tables ?

Answer (score 5):

use this way

```
db.execSQL("create table if not exists table_name(rank int, correct_answer int, optionselect int);";
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I was creating multiple tables and had the same TABLE_NAME like this.  This was causing a conflict.

```
// Define Table
public static final class groupMembersTable implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "group_members_list";
    public static final String COLUMN_GROUP_FIREBASE_ID = "group_firebase_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_MEMBER_FIREBASE_ID = "from_user_id";

}
```