# Android- Must I check if table exists in SqliteHelper.onCreate()?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I move database create table from Applcation.onCreate to SqliteHelper.onCreate.

In Application, I must check if table already exists.
But in SqliteHelper, as it's called on creation of database file, I don't think it's nessasary to use "IF NOT EXISTS"

```
CREATE TABLE {TABLE_NAME} IF NOT EXISTS (_id bla bla);
```

Can I change this sql to below?

```
CREATE TABLE {TABLE_NAME} (_id bla bla)
```

EDIT ---------

I asked if SqliteHelper.onCreate can called several times.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571969/sqliteexception-table-already-exists/16572000#16572000

Comment: I think it's not for my case. As I don't need onUpgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. But the first method is always encouraged!

Comment: Thanks. I think this's the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`onCreate()` will only be called if the database does not exist. Adding `IF NOT EXISTS` is therefore not necessary and would only confuse people reading and maintaining the code.

Also, the syntax would be `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name`.